# User monitoring/tracking in Akka.NET

Tags: .net, akka.net

I'm trying to make myself comfortable in Akka.NET and this is working pretty good. However I'm trying to find a way to track user interaction with the actor-system.

For example, if UserX creates a new user and thus a new account I would like to track the fact that UserX initiated the flow of messages and also include a token (or tracking ID) in the message/event flow that results from the user creation.

Is there a way to accomplish this or do I best create a base class that contains these properties (InitiatorId, TrackingId, ...) for each message/event and fill them each time I Tell, Ask and/or reply?

At the very end I'd like to have all this information arrive in Elastic through Beats.

What's your verdict?

Answer (score 1):

There is no baked in way for Akka to track the data you are looking for. In our application, we have base command/event classes from which all of our commands and events in our domain inherit from.  These have properties like `SourceId` and `PerformedBy`.  In our environment, Akka is running in an API and we set these properties directly in the API controllers.

FYI, you might want to look into [Akka.Monitoring](https://github.com/petabridge/akka-monitoring) for integrating your actor system with other monitoring tools!